# Jasmine Js tests with different window sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I was wondering if there is any way using Jasmine js to resize the browser window to test mobile css and responsive layouts.

I know Protractor has a function browser.manage().window().setSize(320, 480); can I reproduce something like this?